# eclipse rcp : custom drawing on composite which has a FillLayout not work

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am trying to add a PaintListener to draw a top border on a Composite :

```
pageComposite.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                e.gc.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_NORMAL_SHADOW));
                e.gc.drawLine(0, 0, pageComposite.getBounds().width, 0);
            }

        });
```

but if the **pageComposite** is set with a **FillLayout**, the border will not be drawn.

```
Composite c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        c.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        new Label(c, SWT.NONE).setText("类方法列表页面，尚未实现");
        return c;
```

the composite created in above code looks like this:
[image]
another composite has a FormLayout:

```
final Composite c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        c.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        Label l = new Label(c, SWT.NONE); 
        l.setText("角色用户机构列表页面，尚未实现");

        FormData fd_content = new FormData();
        fd_content.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        fd_content.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        l.setLayoutData(fd_content);
        return c;
```

[image]
Did I miss anything ?
best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the SWT `org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout` your `paint event listener` is **not getting called** and that's why your border is not getting drawn.

The reason is when you use `FillLayout` like this:

```
FillLayout fillLayout = new FillLayout();
composite.setLayout(fillLayout);
```

Then you are not setting any additional decorations like `indentation`, `margin` etc and hence an OS level `update` is not called on your window.

**If you want to make it work** then set some additional layout data like `marginHeight`. For example:

```
FillLayout fillLayout = new FillLayout();
fillLayout.marginHeight = 5;
composite.setLayout(fillLayout);
```

This is how it looks like after setting the above said layout decoration (note the top border):

[image]

**`>>Code`**

I have put some commented code. Try to remove the comment and see how it behaves.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class FillLayoutTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout()); shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        final Color c = new Color(display, new RGB(127, 127, 127));

        final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FillLayout fillLayout = new FillLayout();
        fillLayout.marginHeight = 5;
        composite.setLayout(fillLayout);
        //composite.setLayout(new GridLayout()); composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER).setText("Hello World!!");
        new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER).setText("Hello World Version 2.0!!");

        composite.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                e.gc.setForeground(c);
                e.gc.drawLine(0, 0, composite.getParent().getBounds().width, 0);
                //throw new RuntimeException();
            }

        });

        shell.open();
        shell.pack();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }       
        if(c != null && !c.isDisposed())
            c.dispose();

        if(display != null && !display.isDisposed())
            display.dispose();
    }
}
```